# Application insights alerts to microsoft teams

Tags: azure, azure-functions, webhooks, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I am trying to create an azure function alert from application insights to be send to microsoft teams webhook.
I have setup a webhook in microsoft teams, however I can't get it linked with application insights in the azure portal.
The application insights alert rules allow email/sms/voice but not custom setup for webhook

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log-webhook

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking at is the [Configure notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups#configure-notifications) blade, that lets you define a list of notifications to send when an alert is triggered.

What you need to do instead is move ahead to the [Configure actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups#configure-actions) blade as shown in the screenshot below, configure the **Action Type** as **Webhook**, and enter your Function App URL.

[image: Configure Actions]

Be sure to enable the [common alert schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-common-schema), which provides the advantage of having a single extensible and unified alert payload across all the alert services in Azure Monitor.

Here are some additional resources to check out:

- [Sending Azure Monitor alerts to Microsoft Teams](https://christofer.lof.io/2020/06/05/sending-azure-monitor-alerts-to-teams.html)
- [Post Azure Monitor Alerts in Microsoft Teams Channel](https://www.itinsights.org/Post-Azure-Monitor-Alerts-in-Microsoft-Teams-Channel)